# ¿Como escribir en un archivo txt estructurado con python?

Tags: python, xml, txt

Hola comentaré mi problema:

extraigo de una carpeta n xml y tengo que poner los valores en el txt que se encuentran dentro de la carpeta que un usuario sube, el problema es que actualmente con el Código de abajo si pone los datos pero no en la estructura que ya tiene el txt, para llenar el txt se hace de la siuginete manera:

1. Desde la columna que se llama IdDocumento hasta TasaOCuotaT
2. Todos los valores se llenan alineados a la izquierda o empezando desde la izquierda a Excepción de la columna TipoCambioDR que su valor es fijo entonces por regla general viene llena desde que el usuario proporciona el txt pero de no ser así, se llenaría desde la parte medía
3. El txt se tiene que sobre escribir o generar uno nuevo, pero con toda la información que contiene y respetando cada espacio que contenga

Para llenarlo mi idea era la siguiente:

1. Cada xml es una fila entonces tienen que haber un bucle que itere el primer xml
2. Encontrar las coordenadas de cada columna y llenarlo debajo de cada columna
3. Aun no se que es mejor si remover el texto que ya se encuentra escrito y escribir la fila entera o mediante el IdDocumento si se encuentra poblado, solo llenar los campos que hagan falta

Dejo las capturas de como llega el txt y el output del txt

La extracción de los datos ya los tengo correctamente dejo la lista:

```
Esta parte se extrae del nodo 
<cfdi:Complemento> 
IdDocumento = UUID 
 
Esta parte se extrae del nodo 
<cfdi:Comprobante> Serie  = W (este es valor siempre es el mismo) 
Folio = Folio 
MonedaDR  = Moneda 
TipoCambioDR =  1.0000000000 (este es valor siempre es el mismo)           
MetodoDePagoDR = MetodoPago 
NumParcialidad = 1 (este es valor siempre es el mismo) 
ImpSaldoAnt = Total          
ImpPagado = Total     
ImpSaldoInsoluto = .00 (este es valor siempre es el mismo)       
CadPago = Siempre se deja vacio    
ObjetoImp = ObjetoImp Tipo = RE (este es valor siempre es el mismo)              
 
Este apartado se extrae del nodo: <cfdi:Retenciones> 
Base  = Base                 
Importe = Importe                 
ImpuestoR = Impuesto      
TipoFactorR = Tasa (este es valor siempre es el mismo)      
TasaOCuotaR =  TasaOCuota     
Tipo =  TR (este es valor siempre es el mismo)                           
 
Este apartado se extrae del nodo: <cfdi:Traslados> 
Base  = Base                 
Importe = Importe                 
ImpuestoT = Impuesto      
TipoFactorT = Tasa (este es valor siempre es el mismo)      
TasaOCuotaT =  TasaOCuota    

Codigo para extraer los datos:

def extraer_datos_xml(ruta_archivo_xml):
# Parsear el archivo XML
tree = ET.parse(ruta_archivo_xml)
root = tree.getroot()

# Espacio de nombres
ns = {
    'cfdi': 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4',
    'tfd': 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital'
}

# Extraer los datos requeridos
datos = {}

# Extraer el UUID del nodo <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital>
complemento = root.find('.//cfdi:Complemento/tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital', ns)
if complemento is not None:
    datos['IdDocumento'] = complemento.attrib.get('UUID')
else:
    raise ValueError("No se pudo encontrar el nodo 'TimbreFiscalDigital' en el archivo XML.")

concepto = root.find('.//cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto', ns)
if concepto is not None:
    datos['ObjetoImp'] = concepto.attrib.get('ObjetoImp', '')


# Extraer datos del nodo <cfdi:Comprobante>
comprobante = root.find('.', ns)
if comprobante is not None:
    datos['Folio'] = comprobante.attrib.get('Folio', '')
    datos['MonedaDR'] = comprobante.attrib.get('Moneda', '')
    datos['MetodoDePagoDR'] = comprobante.attrib.get('MetodoPago', '')
    datos['ImpSaldoAnt'] = comprobante.attrib.get('Total', '')
    datos['ImpPagado'] = comprobante.attrib.get('Total', '')  # Igual a Total de Comprobante
    datos['CadPago'] = ''  # Siempre vacío


  # Extraer datos de los nodos <cfdi:Retenciones> y <cfdi:Traslados>
impuestos = root.find('.//cfdi:Impuestos', ns)

# Extraer información de traslados
traslado = impuestos.find('.//cfdi:Traslados/cfdi:Traslado', ns)
if traslado is not None:
    tasaOCuotaT = traslado.get('TasaOCuota')
    if tasaOCuotaT.startswith('0'):
        tasaOCuotaT = tasaOCuotaT[1:]  # Elimina el '0' inicial


    datos.update({
        'BaseT': traslado.get('Base'),
        'ImporteT': traslado.get('Importe'),
        'ImpuestoT': traslado.get('Impuesto'),
        'TipoFactorT': 'Tasa',  # Valor constante
        'TasaOCuotaT': tasaOCuotaT,
        'TipoT': 'TT'  # Valor constante
    })

# Extraer información de retenciones
concepto_retencion = root.find('.//cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion', ns)
if concepto_retencion is not None:
    tasaOCuotaR = concepto_retencion.get('TasaOCuota')
    if tasaOCuotaR.startswith('0'):
        tasaOCuotaR = tasaOCuotaR[1:]  # Elimina el '0' inicial


    datos.update({
        'BaseR': concepto_retencion.get('Base'),
        'ImporteR': concepto_retencion.get('Importe'),
        'ImpuestoR': concepto_retencion.get('Impuesto'),
        'TipoFactorR': concepto_retencion.get('TipoFactor'),
        'TasaOCuotaR': tasaOCuotaR
    })

   
    if traslado is None and concepto_retencion  is None:
        raise ValueError("No se pudo encontrar los nodos 'Traslado' o 'Retencion' en el archivo XML.")

return datos
```

Codigo que tengo implementado para llenar el txt con los datos

```
def encontrar_indices_y_anchos_columnas(linea_encabezados, lista_columnas):
        indices = {}
        anchos = {}
        for columna in lista_columnas:
            indice = linea_encabezados.find(columna)
            if indice != -1:
                indices[columna] = indice
                # Encontrar el ancho de la columna
                if columna != lista_columnas[-1]:  # Si no es la última columna
                    indice_siguiente = linea_encabezados.find(lista_columnas[lista_columnas.index(columna) + 1])
                    anchos[columna] = indice_siguiente - indice
                else:  # Para la última columna
                    anchos[columna] = len(linea_encabezados) - indice
        return indices, anchos
    
    def escribir_en_txt(ruta_archivo_txt, datos):
        lista_columnas = ['IdDocumento', 'Serie', 'Folio', 'MonedaDR', 'TipoCambioDR', 'MetodoDePagoDR', 
                          'NumParcialidad', 'ImpSaldoAnt', 'ImpPagado', 'ImpSaldoInsoluto', 'CadPago', 
                          'ObjetoImp', 'Tipo', 'BaseR', 'ImporteR', 'ImpuestoR', 'TipoFactorR', 
                          'TasaOCuotaR', 'BaseT', 'ImporteT', 'ImpuestoT', 'TipoFactorT', 'TasaOCuotaT']
    with open(ruta_archivo_txt, 'r') as file:
        lineas = file.readlines()

    # Buscar la línea de encabezados y encontrar los índices y anchos de las columnas
    indices_columnas, anchos_columna = {}, {}
    posicion_encabezado = None
    for i, linea in enumerate(lineas):
        if 'IdDocumento' in linea:
            indices_columnas, anchos_columna = encontrar_indices_y_anchos_columnas(linea, lista_columnas)
            posicion_encabezado = i
            break

    if posicion_encabezado is None:
        raise ValueError("No se encontró el encabezado en el archivo TXT.")

    # Actualizar la primera fila de datos si es necesario
    if len(lineas) > posicion_encabezado + 1:
        for columna, indice in indices_columnas.items():
            inicio = indice
            fin = inicio + anchos_columna[columna]
            if lineas[posicion_encabezado + 1][inicio:fin].strip() == '' and columna in datos:
                valor_formateado = datos[columna].ljust(anchos_columna[columna])
                lineas[posicion_encabezado + 1] = (lineas[posicion_encabezado + 1][:inicio] +
                                                   valor_formateado +
                                                   lineas[posicion_encabezado + 1][fin:])
    
    # Verificar y añadir nuevas filas de datos si es necesario
    fila_para_escribir = posicion_encabezado + 2
    while fila_para_escribir < len(lineas):
        if any(lineas[fila_para_escribir][indice:indice + anchos_columna[columna]].strip() == '' for columna, indice in indices_columnas.items()):
            nueva_linea = ' ' * len(lineas[fila_para_escribir])
            for columna, indice in indices_columnas.items():
                if columna in datos and lineas[fila_para_escribir][indice:indice + anchos_columna[columna]].strip() == '':
                    valor_formateado = datos[columna].ljust(anchos_columna[columna])
                    nueva_linea = nueva_linea[:indice] + valor_formateado + nueva_linea[indice + anchos_columna[columna]:]
            lineas[fila_para_escribir] = nueva_linea
            break
        fila_para_escribir += 1

    # Reescribir el archivo con el nuevo contenido
    with open(ruta_archivo_txt, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(lineas)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: texto en negrita][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][4]][4]

[image: ouput]

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer de tu código a un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sea más facil ayudarte. Además, vendría bien que entres más en detalle con respecto a como se debe llenar el txt y cual es el resultado esperado.